# Como especificar el nombre de la etiqueta de una lista con clases heredadas Xml C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Buen día, como están?

Estoy realizando un programa donde necesito serializar una lista de elementos que heredan de una clase "general" que se llama Description, y las que heredan son Cabezal, Detalle y Pago, donde les indique cual seria el Root del XML, sin embargo, no se presencia en el XML que genere (Todas las clases tienen el Root con el nombre en mayúscula) sino se diferencia con el type, ¿Cómo puedo hacer que ese elemento tenga el nombre que definí en el XmlRoot?.

También, quiero definir el nombre de la etiqueta del elemento padre que seria "ArrayOfDescription" a "DOCUMENTO", ¿Cómo se podría hacer?.

```
//Esta es la forma de como lo estoy serializando
        IParsearVenta parsearVenta = new ParsearVentaX();
        List<List<Description>> ventas = parsearVenta.ParsearVenta(DateTime.Parse("2021-12-10 00:00:00"), DateTime.Parse("2021-12-10 23:00:00"));
        var stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Description>), new Type[]
        {
            typeof(Cabezal),
            typeof(Detalle),
            typeof(Pago)
        });
        ventas.ForEach(venta =>
        {
            serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, venta);
            Console.WriteLine(stringWriter.ToString());
        });
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "DOCUMENTO")]
public class Description
{
    public Description() { }
}
 public class Cabezal : Description
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MODELO")]
    public string Modelo { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FECHA")]
    public string Fecha { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "NUMERO")]
    public int Numero { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CLINOMBRE")]
    public string ClienteNombre { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CLIRAZON")]
    public string ClienteRazon { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CLIDEPTO")]
    public string ClienteDepartamento { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CLICIUDAD")]
    public string ClienteCiudad { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CLIDIR")]
    public string ClienteDirection { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CONTACTO")]
    public string Contacto { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "COMENTARIO")]
    public string Comentario { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MENSAJE")]
    public string Mensaje { get; set; }
    public Cabezal() { }
}
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "DETALLE")]
public class Detalle : Description
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ARTICULO")]
    public string Articulo { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "LISTAPRECIO")]
    public string ListaPrecio { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SUBART1")]
    public string Talle { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "SUBART2")]
    public string Color { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CANTIDAD")]
    public string Cantidad { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "PRECIO")]
    public double Precio { get; set; }
    public Detalle() { }
}
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "PAGO")]
public class Pago : Description
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ENTIDAD")]
    public string Entidad { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CUOTAS")]
    public string Cuotas { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "AUTORIZNUM")]
    public string AutorizNum { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MONTO")]
    public double Monto { get; set; }
}
```

[image]